# Parameters and Android manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i'd like to externally define the Android application name using and external class - meaning i'd like to have an external class such as:

```
public class Config
{
    public final static String AppName = "TestApp";
}
```

And i'd like the manifest to use this class's final variable as the app's name, or another option is to set the strings.xml using that external variable.

Could this be done? if yes - how? if not - is there any other way to get around this?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry for question but not answer. Why is the issue to have several manifest files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. You can define your variables at values files (strings.xml, dimens.xml, colors.xml, ...) and reference on it by **@string/...**, **@dimen/...**, **@color/...**.